# Bigquery event streaming gives "Could not fetch url" sometimes

Tags: google-bigquery

We just made some tests with streaming events directly to bigquery which was partly a success but I noticed that one event was missing (of ca 20) and when searching the log I noticed that this particular event failed due to

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not fetch URL: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<project-name>/datasets/<datasetname>/tables/events_app6_v6_201507/insertAll
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:140)
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:45)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.fetchResponse(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:502)
```

So my questions to anyone has noticed the same is:

A) How likely it is that an insert fails?

B) What would be the best pattern for us to handle these kind of errors.

Taken into account that we are streaming huge amount of events and don't have time for any lengthy error handling.

One approach would be to simply ignore errors but we can not accept loosing 5% of our events.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since streaming has a limited payload size, see [Quota policy](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) it's easier to talk about times, as the payload is limited in the same way to both of us, but I will mention other side effects too.

We measure between 1200-2500 ms for each streaming request, and this was consistent over the last month as you can see in the chart.

[image]

We seen several side effects although:

- the request randomly fails with type 'Backend error'
- the request randomly fails with type 'Connection error'
- the request randomly fails with type 'timeout' (watch out here, as only some rows are failing and not the whole payload)
- some other error messages are non descriptive, and they are so vague that they don't help you, just retry.
- we see hundreds of such failures each day, so they are pretty much constant, and not related to Cloud health.

For all these we opened cases in paid Google Enterprise Support, but unfortunately they didn't resolved it. It seams the recommended option to take for these is an exponential-backoff with retry, even the support told to do so. Which personally doesn't make me happy.

Also the failure rate fits the 99.9% uptime we have in the SLA, so there is no reason for objection.

There's something to keep in mind in regards to the SLA, it's a very strictly defined structure, the details are [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla). The 99.9% is uptime not directly translated into fail rate. What this means is that if BQ has a 30 minute downtime one month, and then you do 10,000 inserts within that period but didn't do any inserts in other times of the month, it will cause the numbers to be skewered. This is why we suggest a exponential backoff algorithm. The SLA is explicitly based on uptime and not error rate, but logically the two correlates closely if you do streaming inserts throughout the month at different times with backoff-retry setup. Technically, you should experience on average about 1/1000 failed insert if you are doing inserts through out the month if you have setup the proper retry mechanism.

You can check out this chart about your project health:
https://console.developers.google.com/project/YOUR-APP-ID/apiui/apiview/bigquery?tabId=usage&duration=P1D

You need to built a retry mechanism to re-queue your events. As mentioned earlier the 'timeout' type is special as only some rows are timeouted, and some are success. This means you need to parse the response, and see which timeouted and re-queue only those. If you requeue all your payload you might end up with duplicates.

---

You need to rethink the approach with `async processes`. In order to finish sooner, you need to run in parallel multiple workers, the streaming performance will be the same. Just having 10 workers in parallel it means time will be 10 times less.

Processing in background IO bound or cpu bound tasks is now a common practice in most web applications. There's plenty of software to help build background jobs, some based on a messaging system like [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/).

Basically, you needed to distribute insert jobs across a closed network, to prioritize them, and consume(run) them. Well, that's exactly what Beanstalkd provides.

Beanstalkd gives the possibility to organize jobs in tubes, each tube corresponding to a job type.

You need an API/producer which can put jobs on a tube, let's say a json representation of the row. This was a killer feature for our use case. So we have an API which gets the rows, and places them on tube, this takes just a few milliseconds, so you could achieve fast response time.

On the other part, you have now a bunch of jobs on some tubes. You need an agent. An agent/consumer can reserve a job.

It helps you also with job management and retries: When a job is successfully processed, a consumer can delete the job from the tube. In the case of failure, the consumer can bury the job. This job will not be pushed back to the tube, but will be available for further inspection.

A consumer can release a job, Beanstalkd will push this job back in the tube, and make it available for another client.

Beanstalkd clients can be found in most common languages, a [web interface](https://github.com/ptrofimov/beanstalk_console) can be useful for debugging.

Comment: Actually we ended up adding all insert failures to a push queue. This solution was quite simple actually. We now streams ca 2M events hourly without any problems so far. There is a certain number of insert failures  but they are handled by the push queue handler. Seems to work quite well.

Comment: @GunnarEketrapp do you guys stream events individually or doing batches? I'm wondering how stressful it'll be on the streaming machines to stream each event separately.

Comment: Yes we stream each event individually.